# Can I send a message instead of a view back as an ActionResult with ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following action in ASP.NET MVC4

```
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                // ?? Need some code here 
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

I have the following code that calls this:

```
$('#article').on('submit', '#loginForm, #registerForm', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var $form = $(this);
     var href= $form.attr('data-href');
     $form.validate();
     if (!$form.valid()) {
         return false;
     }
     var data = $form.serializeArray();
     $.ajax(
     {
         data: data,
         type: 'POST',
         url: href
     })
         .done(submitDone)
         .fail(submitFail);
     function submitDone(content) {
         $('#article').html(content)
     }
     function submitFail() {
         alert("Failed");
     }
     return false;
 });
```

If the registration works I would like to force the whole web page to refresh. Is there 
a way that I can **send back a message from the actionmethod to the javascript** to 
tell it that the registration works and the javascript should refresh the whole 
web page?

I did try return RedirectToLocal("/"); but this definitely does not work. What 
this does is to return a new page and then have it populated in the #article DIV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing that will automatically refresh the browser from the server.

To refresh the browser from the server you'll need to send something from the server to the client indicating that you want to refresh the page. You'll need to write the javascript to look for the indication to refresh the browser.

Client Code

```
function submitDone(content) {

 var json = $.parseJson(content);

  if(json.isSuccess) {

   //Do something here   

  }

     $('#article').html(json.content)

 }
```

Server code

```
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                // ?? Need some code here 
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Json(new {isSuccess = true, content = model});
}
```

I am unsure of what you are trying to accomplish by refreshing the page, if it's to clear out the form fields. The same could be achieved by using JavaScript. By using javascript instead of a page refresh you won't lose page state, such as error messages.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I realize and already agree with what you are saying. My question was is there a way that I could send a message back to my javascript to say success so I could make the js then do a full refresh of the page?

Comment: Sure, wrap your content in JSON. On the client-side simply parse the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

well i can think of a quick javascript trick to refresh a page on success like this

```
function submitDone(content) {
     window.location.reload();
 }
```

this will reload the page on the success.